# Fixing Craft deprecation errors general question

Tags: deprecation

I want to fix some deprecation errors on my site but would like to know a little more about how this works so that I know they are actually fixed and I haven't just cleared/hidden them.

If I visit a page on my site (local version) where it appears an error has occurred I'm still seeing the last occurrence of this as being last week, when I would expect it to be just now - I'm assuming that this isn't 'live' data and it's going from some sort of log. If so how often does this log refresh, and is there a way I can do it manually so I can see something more like live info as I'm fixing stuff?

Any advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deprecation info is written to the database every time the code or template in question is executed. So if the last occurrence of a warning was last week, it might mean that it's fixed, or it might mean that this particular route / code path has not been executed in a week. If you clear the warnings in the CMS, they will not reappear until that template is used again.

I usually check which line the deprecation warning is referring to and fix it. Then I clear the deprecation warnings and reload the page with the template, or perform the steps that cause that template / code path to be executed. If the deprecation warning doesn't show up again after that, the issue is fixed.

Comment: that's great thank you. So it is in fact live, I just undid my fixes and hey presto now showing as error just now :)